# Como marcar todos los checkbox de un Listview a traves de otro Checkbox

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo el siguiente xml:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/AlertDialog_TPV_family_Style_Title"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Modificación Articulos" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Seleccione Articulos vendibles"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/black"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/mTodos"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Marcar todos"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerfamilias"></Spinner>



<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listaArticulos"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerPadding="8dp"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"></ListView>
```

Esta compuesto por varios elementos, entre ellos un ListView y un Checkbox, bien lo que quiero hacer es que marcando ese checkbox me marque todos los checkbox que aparecen en el ListView, os dejo el xml de los item del ListView:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/articulo"/>
```

Muy sencillo, un textview el cual le asocio valores de una lista y un checkbox, todo esto se ejecuta en un dialogo el cual he creado:

```
public class DialogGArticulos extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View parentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_articulos, null);
    final ArrayList[] listaart = new ArrayList[1];


    final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) parentView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerfamilias);
    final ListView listView = (ListView) parentView.findViewById(R.id.listaArticulos);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) parentView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);



    builder.setView(parentView);

    //SPINNER
    ArrayList listaFamilias = new ArrayList(Utility.dbHelper.getAllFamiliesAndGroups());
    Log.i("DialogDArticulos","listaFamilias "+ listaFamilias);
    ArrayAdapter adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.spinner_item,Utility.dbHelper.getAllFamiliesAndGroups());
    adapterSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapterSpinner);
    Log.i("DialogArticulos","spinner.getSelectedItem().toString() "+ spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    spinner.setSelection(0);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listaart[0] = new ArrayList(Utility.dbHelper.getArticlesByFam(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
            listView.setAdapter(new GArticleAdapter(getActivity(), listaart[0]));
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });


    //LISTVIEW
    listaart[0] = new ArrayList(Utility.dbHelper.getArticlesByFam(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()));
    //listaart = Utility.dbHelper.getArticlesByFam(spinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
    Log.i("DialogArticulos","gArt by fam "+ listaart[0]);
    listView.setAdapter(new GArticleAdapter(getActivity(), listaart[0]));


    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            for (int i = 0; i<listaart.length;i++){
                //Bucle que recoree los elementos que se muestran en la lista con la intencion de marcarlos todos con algun metodo.
            }
        }
    });

return builder.create();
}
```

}

Tambien os dejo por aqui mi adaptador para que le echeis un ojo, es un adaptador personalizado:

```
public class GArticleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
ArrayList listaDatos;


public GArticleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listaDatos){
    this.context = context;
    this.listaDatos = listaDatos;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listaDatos.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listaDatos.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_articulos, parent,false);
    }
    TextView articulo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.articulo);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    articulo.setText(listaDatos.get(position).toString());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

Alguien sabe como podria marcar todos los checkbox del ListView marcando el checkbox que esta fuera de este ListView??

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pon el botón del check box a la escucha de una accion `on click`, y cuando su valor cambie, 
cojes el `ArrayList` que pasas por parámetro al adaptador que utilizas para poblar el `ListView` y le haces un bucle `for` cambiando todos los valores de sus `check box` y cuando salga del bucle llamas al método `notifyDataSetChanged()` de tu adaptador.

Comment: Gracias por responder, he usado un .setOnCheckedChangeListaener en el checkbox y he realizado el bucle for para recorrer los valores de la lista, pero a la hora de acceder al checkbox, no hay ningun checkbox en la lista que le paso al adaptador, no se que metodo puedo usar pero no hay ningun get con buena pinta, un saludo.

Comment: Me he guiado por esta otra pregunta un saludo. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553186/android-checkbox-listview-select-all-disable-enable